# Custom Fields not showing up for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I'm a little new to WordPress development and am SO frustrated-- I created some custom post types, and am trying to add custom fields to them. For some reason, the fields will just not show up when I try to add a new post!!! Here is my code--this is in the custom post type file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Art Beat
 * Plugin URI: #
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: bjorkland
 * Author URI: http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s
 * Description: A custom post type
 * License: GPL2
 */

class ArtBeat {

function __construct() {
  add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_custom_post_type' ) );
}
function register_custom_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'artbeat', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Art Beats', 'post type general name', 'artbeat' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Art Beat', 'post type singular name', 'artbeat' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Art Beat', 'admin menu', 'artbeat' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Art Beat', 'add new on admin bar', 'artbeat' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New Art Beat', 'art', 'artbeat' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Art Beat', 'artbeat' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Art Beat', 'artbeat' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Art Beat', 'artbeat' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Art Beat', 'artbeat' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Art Beats', 'artbeat' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Art Beats', 'artbeat' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Art Beat:', 'artbeat' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Art Beat found.', 'artbeat' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Art Beat found in Trash.', 'artbeat' ),
    ),

    // Frontend
    'has_archive'        => false,
    'public'             => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => false,

    // Admin
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-businessman',
    'menu_position' => 10,
    'query_var'     => true,
    'show_in_menu'  => true,
    'show_ui'       => true,
    'supports'      => array(
        'title',
        'author',
        'comments',
    ),
) );
}
}

$ArtBeat = new ArtBeat;


function add_artbeat_meta_boxes() {
 add_meta_box("artbeat_contact_meta", "Contact Details", "add_contact_details_artbeat_meta_box", "artbeats", "normal", "low");
}
   function add_contact_details_artbeat_meta_box()
  {
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom( $post->ID );

?>
 <style>.width99 {width:99%;}</style>
 <p>
<label>Date:</label><br />
  <textarea rows="5" name="date" class="width99"><?= @$custom["date"][0] ?></textarea>
   </p>
   <p>
     <label>Museum:</label><br />
     <input type="text" name="museum" value="<?= @$custom["museum"][0] ?>"    class="width99" />
  </p>
  <?php
}

function save_artbeat_custom_fields(){
 global $post;

if ( $post )
{
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "date", @$_POST["date"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "museum", @$_POST["museum"]);
}
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_artbeat_meta_boxes' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_artbeat_custom_fields' );
```

Comment: You should not use `@` error suppression. Instead check if the data is available with `if ( isset() )` or `if ( empty() )` and display a default (or nothing) if it is not present. Also make sure that you use the proper `esc_*()` functions to escape possible unsafe data like for e.g. `$_POST` data before your save it to the database. Else you might find yourself getting hacked pretty quick.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created an Class in your plugin then you should use the action hook for admin_init in class only just like you have used "init"

```
function __construct() {
  add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_custom_post_type' ) );
  add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'add_artbeat_meta_boxes' ) );
  add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_artbeat_custom_fields' ) );
}
```

Hope this will help you out.